# Copy and delete Pathlib.Path

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to copy or delete a Path object, whether it is a file, a symlink, or a directory.
I don't want to monkey patch Pathlib so I created some surrogate functions for those operations:

```
def copy(src: Path, target: Path):
    """ copy the file, symlink or path (empty or not)
    file/folder is replaced if already existing"""
    if src.is_file():
        shutil.copy(src, target)
    elif src.is_dir():
        shutil.copytree(src, target)

def delete(df: Path):
    """ delete the file, symlink or path (empty or not) """
    if df.is_dir() and not df.is_symlink():
        for dp, dn, fn in df.walk(top_down=False):
            for f in fn:
                (dp/f).unlink()
            dp.rmdir()
    if df.is_symlink() or df.is_file():
        df.unlink()
```

My goal is not to care about whether the Path exists or not. This verification will be carried out by the caller.

Do you see something missing or something that could be written in a more pythonic way?
Should I handle some errors in it?

**EDIT:**
One of the application for a dotfile manager would be:

```
def link_dotfile(df: Path):
    """ create a symlink from dotfile in the profile folder
    onto the home folder """
    home_dotfile = Path.home() / df.name
    if home_dotfile.exists():
        delete(home_dotfile)

    home_dotfile.symlink_to(df)
```

It removes the home dotfile which has the same name as the one stored in a third party folder and then creates a symlink pointing to it.

Comment: What is the purpose of these functions? If it's for exposing to a user who wants some simple file operations, then maybe it makes sense. If it's for some specific operation in a program then this is probably not well-advised.

Comment: Let's say those are shortcut for basic operations all along my program. For more fine operations I will for sure get back to the vanilla library methods.

Comment: _all along my program_ definitely means that these are not well-applied functions. More often than not, within a program you'll know whether something is supposed to be a directory or not.

Comment: If you depict one or two places where these functions are called, I can offer more detail in an answer.

Comment: I have edited my post.

Answer (score 3):

## design of Public API

The [Path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)
routines were carefully designed to do just what they promise,
without unpleasant surprises.

This API assumes that caller wants either of a file or a tree
to be manipulated.
Fine, I will assume that's what caller wants.
The optional `Path` annotations in the signatures are very nice.

When documenting such an API, your docstrings should
be pretty explicit about the fact that whole subtrees
maybe acted on, causing e.g. `rm -rf` behavior.
As written, I find the use of "path" in an English sentence
to be a bit on the vague side.
My initial interpretation of "empty path" was `Path("")`,
clearly different from Author's Intent.
OTOH a reference to "empty subdirectory" would have
immediately illuminated the situation.

The {src, target} identifiers are very nice, thank you.

## behavior differs from a familiar library

On first reading I imagined that `delete()` was roughly
[`df.unlink()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.unlink) +
[`shutil.rmtree(df)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree),
whichever was appropriate.
But upon reading it I realized that
there's no [test suite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase) which illustrates `mkdir foo; date > foo/date.txt; ln -s foo bar; python -c '... delete("bar")'`.
As caller, I personally find it extremely surprising that
`bar` got nuked (fine!), yet `foo` and its contents continue to exist.
It seems pretty clear to me that a request to `delete("bar")`
should obliterate the pointer and thing(s) pointed at.
Oddly, the code won't do that.

It is perfectly fine to specify different behavior.
But you should be pretty clear when you do that,
drawing distinctions between the two libraries.
Then potential callers will understand the
advantages of *your* library for their particular use case.

## meaningful identifiers

```
def delete(df: Path):  ...
        for dp, dn, fn in df.walk( ... ):
```

`df` is part of your Public API, and so has a heavier
documentation burden than those three local variables.
Please use a more descriptive name such as `target` or `deleted_filespec`.

The three locals are *fine*, but I would have appreciated
`root, directories, filenames`, or simply copying
`dirpath, dirnames, filenames` straight out of the
[man page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.walk).
In particular, I got hung up on "singular, singular, singular"
and was thinking we'd get one triple per file,
when of course the underlying API actually
returns "singular, plural_iterable, plural_iterable".
Short names *can* be fine for locals, but hopefully they
won't lead the Gentle Reader astray.

## common lisp identifiers

```
                (dp/f).unlink()
```

Please don't write it in that manner.
It looks like we're working with Scheme
or with the Common Lisp variable `dp/f`,
after executing `(defvar dp/f "foo")`.

When writing python code we surround `/` slash and other
operators with whitespace.
Simplest way to accomplish that would be from the bash prompt:
[$ black *.py](https://pypi.org/project/black).

## clear parameter names

```
def link_dotfile(df: Path):
```

Apparently here I should read it as "dotfile" pathname,
rather than as "deleted file".
Please spell it out: `dotfile: Path`.

Also, I found "onto" in the docstring confusing,
in the sense that I failed to understand this function's
[contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract).
I thought we would be creating a new link to an existing dotfile.
Turns out that we nuke a dotfile and then link out to a file
within some pip-installed package subtree.

Consider verifying that `df.exists()` before doing anything drastic.

Arguably there's no need to verify that `home_dotfile.exists()`,
since the `delete()` call will just be a no-op.
*Do* consider tacking on a keyword default parameter
of `nonexistant_ok=True` in its signature
so callers will understand that aspect.

Answer (score 1):

Let's pick on `link_dotfile` and assume that all other uses are similar in that they only operate on a file or a directory, not either. This is typical in a lot of applications. The give-away is in the name: `link_dotfile` links a file. It doesn't link a directory (or at least that behaviour has been obscured by nomenclature). If the names tell the truth, then

- Delete `copy` and `delete` from your codebase; they supply an API choice that should not exist
- Rewrite the likes of `link_dotfile` to

```py
home_dotfile = Path.home() / df.name
home_dotfile.unlink(missing_ok=True)
home_dotfile.symlink_to(df)
```

If the names *don't* tell the truth and `link_dotfile` might truly link a directory, then name it something like `link_dotpath`.